# MacBook Air hot after sleeping

Tags: macbook-pro, temperature

I am experiencing strange issue with my MacBook Air (2011, with Mavericks):

- I don't like to turn off my machine, so I usually just close the lid and put my laptop to backpack before I go to sleep
- I take it off the bag in the morning at the work, do only basic work (email etc. - no suspicious things in Activity Monitor), but my MacBook Air will get to high temperatures (90℃ for CPU, runs fan at 6000 RPM).

I can 'solve' that by putting computer to sleep, wait a while (~30 sec), wake it up again and temperatures will get back to normal. I already tried resetting the SCM.

Notes:

- I don't keep MagSafe connected to my Macbook Air during the night
- I usually have plenty of running apps on my laptop (4GB of RAM, but Virtual Memory usually tops 10 GB)
- I always run 1 instance of CentOS in VirtualBox (with Oracle database)

Comment: The VM would be the first place I'd check.  What happens if you pause it before sleeping?  If you save state and close?

Comment: I will try tonight and update this post.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I was able to reproduce the same problem even with paused VM. Any other suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: I tried disabling deep sleep and see if that helps:

http://pocketpccentral.net/blog/2011/08/02/disable-safe-sleep-lion/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Disabling the deep sleep](http://pocketpccentral.net/blog/2011/08/02/disable-safe-sleep-lion/) seemed to have fixed the issue for me.